# Stream Management (XEP-0198) in Prosody

Tags: xmppframework, prosody-im, stream-management

I am using Prosody for stream management. But I am suffering from some issues.

How can I ensure that stream management is enabled on prosody ? Is there any command to test on terminal ?

I also tried to add `mod_smacks.lua` modules in modules. but I don't know how to enable it on server.

I am using XMPPFramework as chat client on iOS. There is already a method to check support for stream management or not, but it is returning me always false so far.

Please help me out to enable stream management in prosody.

Answer (score 1):

After you added `mod_smacks.lua` into your `/usr/lib/prosody/modules/` add

```
"smacks";
```

to your

```
modules_enabled = {
...
}
```

in your `/etc/prosody/prosody.cfg.lua` if you want the module to be loaded every time prosody starts.
Then restart prosody.

[Prosodyctl](http://prosody.im/doc/prosodyctl) does not show loaded modules.
You can check if the module is loaded via ad-hoc commands (or [telnet](https://prosody.im/doc/console) if activated). You can even load and unload modules via ad-hoc/telnet.

You get more information about `mod_smacks` [here](https://modules.prosody.im/mod_smacks.html).